# How to use joins in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to sql and I'm not able to figure out how to use joins where we use aliases with pl/sql variables. This is similiar to what my anonymous block looks like

```
DECLARE
 l_count PLS_INTEGER;  
 l_name EmpTable.Name%Type;
BEGIN
   FOR l_row In (
     Select * 
      From User_Tab_Columns
     Where Table_Name = 'EmpTable')
   Loop
     l_name := l_row.Name;
     Select Count(A.l_name)
       INTO l_count
       FROM EmpTable A
      INNER JOIN CustTable B on A.id = B.emp_id;
     DBMS_OUTPUT ("The number of employees who are also customers are " || l_count);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm getting error as 'l_name' must be declared' and "A"."l_name" invalid identifier. The flow makes perfect sense to me. Is there some nuance that i should know of?

Answer (score 1):

l_name is a variable and not part of your SQL expression.  I'm also more of a fan of using NUMBER vs PLS_INTEGER.  I think you would be looking to do something like this:

```
DECLARE
 l_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
   Select Count(A.Name)
     INTO l_count
     FROM EmpTable A
    INNER JOIN CustTable B on A.id = B.emp_id;
   DBMS_OUTPUT ("The number of employees who are also customers are " || l_count);
END;
```

Comment: Is there a way to insert the l_name variable as part of the sql expression?

Comment: On a side note, why the choice of number over pls_number. I thought pls_integer is more efficient and general?

Comment: I've just always used NUMBER in projects over the last 10 years and so no reason to switch it up.  To insert the l_name you would have to add it in a GROUP BY which in turn would give you a count for each name and thus not be able to be inserted into l_name because it was not defined as an array (that I could tell).  You could always build a cursor around the structure and do one name at a time.